# The use of WorkManagerTestInitHelper prevents the WorkManager from completing the retry of the work

Tags: android, android-testing, android-workmanager

When I use:

```
    WorkManagerTestInitHelper.initializeTestWorkManager(context);
    WorkManager workManager =  WorkManager.getInstance();
```

to get the WorkManager instance, the WorkManager fail to achieve retry. 
I will present the simplest test:

```
public class WorkManagerTest {



   Context context;


@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();


}






@Test
public   void testWorker1(){
    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .build();
    OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder updateorderworkerBuilder =
            new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(TestWorker1.class)
                    .setConstraints(constraints)
                    //MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS == 10000
                    .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR,10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);




    OneTimeWorkRequest workRequest = updateorderworkerBuilder.build();
    WorkManager workManager =  WorkManager.getInstance();
    workManager.enqueue(workRequest);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(50000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}


@Test
public   void testWorker2(){
    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                           .build();
    OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder updateorderworkerBuilder =
            new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(TestWorker2.class)
                    .setConstraints(constraints)
                    //MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS == 10000
                    .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR,10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);




    OneTimeWorkRequest workRequest = updateorderworkerBuilder.build();
    WorkManagerTestInitHelper.initializeTestWorkManager(context);
    WorkManager workManager =  WorkManager.getInstance();
    workManager.enqueue(workRequest);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(50000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}


public static class TestWorker1 extends Worker {

    /**
     * Override this method to do your actual background processing.
     *
     * @return The result of the work, corresponding to a {@link Result} value.  If a
     * different value is returned, the result shall be defaulted to
     * {@link Result#FAILURE}.
     */
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Log.d("TEST_WORKER", "inside doWork()1");
        return Result.RETRY;
    }
}


public static class TestWorker2 extends Worker {

    /**
     * Override this method to do your actual background processing.
     *
     * @return The result of the work, corresponding to a {@link Result} value.  If a
     * different value is returned, the result shall be defaulted to
     * {@link Result#FAILURE}.
     */
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Log.d("TEST_WORKER", "inside doWork()2");
        return Result.RETRY;
    }
}
```

}

In the Logcat I see:

```
07-22 23:34:25.184 5346-5388/com.billst.app.debug D/TEST_WORKER: inside doWork()1
07-22 23:34:30.178 5346-5391/com.billst.app.debug D/TEST_WORKER: inside doWork()1
07-22 23:34:40.238 5346-5388/com.billst.app.debug D/TEST_WORKER: inside doWork()1
07-22 23:35:00.300 5346-5391/com.billst.app.debug D/TEST_WORKER: inside doWork()1
07-22 23:35:15.130 5346-5372/com.billst.app.debug D/TEST_WORKER: inside doWork()2
```

I take the same results even when I execute the 2 tests independently. We see that the use of  **WorkManagerTestInitHelper** prevents the WorkManager from completing the retry of the work.

Do I use **WorkManagerTestInitHelper** correctly?

Comment: I do not see a way to simulate that in the docs : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/testing

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simulate retries in test mode. This is intentional because you should be testing your `Worker` and not testing `WorkManager`. You cannot use `WorkManagerTestInitHelper` for this. If you want to test that your `Worker` returns a `Result.retry()` then you could also use the new `TestWorkerBuilder<>` and the `TestListenableWorkerBuilder` APIs.

Here is an example. 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/work/workmanager-testing/src/androidTest/java/androidx/work/testing/TestWorkerBuilderTest.kt

Comment: I can't view this link, it requires login access @Rahul